# WebService request response in Service when app is closed android

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services, android-service

I have a **Service** class in my android app.
This service get user location and send location to server with **ASP** WebService.
Below is my service code :

```java
public class ServiceSendLocation extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "ServiceSendLocation";

    final long milliseconds_sleep = 3000;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        isRunning = true;
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(milliseconds_sleep);
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    getLocationAndSend();

                    if (isRunning)
                        Log.i(TAG, "Service running");
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
}

    private void getLocationAndSend() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service getLocationAndSend");
        LocationManager locationManager = null;
        LocationListener locationListener = new ServiceGetLocation();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Service PERMISSION_GRANTED");
            try {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

                HelperWS.register(structCheckUser.getUserId(), ServiceGetLocation.lat + "", ServiceGetLocation.lng + "", new HelperWS.InsertGpsDriver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(StructInsertGpsDriver success) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Success : " +ServiceGetLocation.lat  + ", " + ServiceGetLocation.lng);
                        Toast.makeText(ServiceSendLocation.this, "success : " +ServiceGetLocation.lat  + ", " + ServiceGetLocation.lng , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFail(String message) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onFail");
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {}
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Service PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        isRunning = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }
}
```

and in manifest :

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        ...>

        <service
            android:name=".SendLocation.ServiceSendLocation" />

    </application>
```

This code sends the location information to the server and get the response form WebService. But when app is closed this code get the location information and also send request but we don't get webService response

Somebody please help me.

Comment: `we don't get webService response` and what you get instead of response?

Comment: @vlad-matvienko nothing, just send request and don't get response

Comment: How are you not getting ConnectionTimeOut ? Whats the Timeout of your request ?

Comment: that is something weird. Maybe you get an error?

Comment: in log when app opened :
request ws method(InsertGpsDriver) = {"UserId":1,"Lat":"0.0","Lng":"0.0"}
webService method(InsertGpsDriver)result raw is:
                                                                                   [{
                                                                                     "result": "2812"
                                                                                   }]
when app closed :
request ws method(InsertGpsDriver) = {"UserId":1,"Lat":"0.0","Lng":"0.0"}
- Just Send Request...